# react post request using axios is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few data and now i want to save it in database using axios post in react.

I have two fields but in both fields coming same data, dont know whats wrong here.

My Code:

```js
 state = {
        salonName: '',
        locationCity: '',
  };
  handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ salonName: event.target.value });
        this.setState({ locationCity: event.target.value });
};
 handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const salonData = {
            salonName: this.state.salonName,
            locationCity: this.state.locationCity,
 };
 axios({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:4200/addsalon",
                headers: {},
                data: {
                    salonName: salonData.salonName,
                    locationCity: salonData.locationCity,
  },
                });
                }
render() {
        return (
<div>
<input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Salon Name..." name="salonName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter City" name="locationCity"  onChange={this.handleChange} />
</div>
```

but i'm getting same value in database like given below:-
{"_id":"60ac7dd4ccfa1c07a8df84d8","salonName":"Delhi","locationCity":"Delhi","__v":0}]

ThankYou for your efforts!

Comment: You're setting both `salonNam` and `locationCity` to the input event target value, so they'll both be the same. One solution is `this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });` instead of the two lines. In the future you should get comfortable debugging your code with `console.log()` to trace where variables are getting set.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andy Ray this is the best way to solve it in single line...

Answer (score 1):

The problem in handle change. you updating both with same if anyone changes

```
 handleChange = event => {
        if(event.target.name ===='salonName'){
        this.setState({ salonName: event.target.value });
        }else if(event.target.name ===='locationCity'){
        this.setState({ locationCity: event.target.value });
        }
};
```